# Angularjs accessing views with direct url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I use `<a href>` or `<a ui-sref>`  ... everything is working fine and I can access all the views.
When I input the link directly into the browser like `http://localhost/#/someurl` it don't work.

if I click on one of the button in the navbar, and then pass my url through `<a href>` or `<a ui-sref>`, it works.

**root.jade**

```
ng-include(src="'partials/navbar.html'")
div(ui-view="")
```

**navbar.jade**
    nav.navbar.navbar-default
        .container-fluid
            .navbar-header
                a.navbar-brand(href="#") Open Service Compendium

```
        ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li
                a(ui-sref="home") Home
            li
                a(ui-sref="test1") test1
            li
                a(ui-sref="test2") test2
```

So if I try to go to

```
http://localhost/#/otherview
```

it doesn't work, I get a blank page with the navbar, but if I click on test1 the url is formed as,

```
http://localhost/#/otherview
```

and it works. It seems a bit logic because `div(ui-view="")` on root.jade will load only the vews that will be clicked on the navbar maybe ? has anyone an idea ?

**root.html**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch']).config(function($stateProvider) {
   $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
  }).state('services', {
    url: '/services/:type',
    templateUrl: 'services.html'
  }).state('services.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'detail.html'
  }).state('test1', {
    url: '/test1',
    templateUrl: 'test1.html'
  }).state('test2', {
    url: '/test2',
    templateUrl: 'test2.html'
  });
});
```

Comment: Show the code where you have defined ui-router states, please

Comment: routing code please!

Comment: @user3235881 I think you need to remove **return**. Just **$stateProvider.state**.

Comment: please follow @Alberto's suggestion and try!

Comment: I did, it still working but still can't access views with direct url :(

Comment: have edited my answer and added a link, which is great to start with jade + Angular

Answer (score 0):

**root.jade**

`ng-include(src="'partials/navbar.html'")
div(ui-view="")`

**navbar.jade** - added div(ng-view)

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li
                a(ui-sref="home") Home
            li
                a(ui-sref="test1") test1
            li
                a(ui-sref="test2") test2
div(ng-view)
```

you can have your partials saved as `.jade` extensions. In routing logic remove `.html` extensions, e.g.,

```
.state('test1', {
    url: '/test1',
    templateUrl: 'test1.html'
  }).state('test2', {
    url: '/test2',
    templateUrl: 'test2.html'
  })
```

becomes,

```
.state('test1', {
    url: '/test1',
    templateUrl: 'test1'
  }).state('test2', {
    url: '/test2',
    templateUrl: 'test2'
  })
```

And try. Recommend to go through the jade, and angular part of [this link](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express)

Comment: It's not working anymore, it's not loading views anymore